# Android: Application specific file download

Tags: android, security, download, sandbox

I am quite new to android application development and at the moment I face a challenge to download pdf files by using my application where those pdfs' can only be accessed by my application, and nobody/no application else can access or view my pdfs.

In iPhone every application has there own sandbox (logical) and resource belongs to those sandboxes' are inaccessible to other application..

What approach is recommended if I intend to make those downloads application dependent and make them unreachable to other application and not even by mounting the android device to a PC.

If, my question doesn't make any sense then please let me know and I will explain more to make my concern clear to you.

Comment: Android is also sandboxed and there is lots of information available on how to store files in an apps private storage.  However, if you download a file to Android, it is impossible to stop someone getting those files.  Same is true for iOS if it's jailbroken.  I think you need to rethink the approach.  Even if you store the files on a server and present them in the app, there are many ways to get the data.

Comment: @Simon I believe application private storage is inaccessible for others unless the device is rooted

Comment: @Alex what is meant by the device is rooted?

Comment: @Maverick_Mrt It's similar to IPhone jailbreaking. It's something user is never supposed to do. You can google for rooting Android or like this.

Comment: Yep, has to be rooted.  But it's trivial.  My point is that once you put a file on the phone, it is not secure - no matter what you do.

Answer (score 1):

Save your files at YourActivity.getContext().[getFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getFilesDir%28%29). Or use [openFileOutput()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)